# mssql - select from another table if no results from the first table

Tags: sql-server

I have to run a query to find a price. I have multiple price lists, each in their own table. customer_price, default_price and minimum_price.

not all price lists have all the products and at times a product might not appear on any price list and then the price needs to return 0 for the price.

so I want to:

```
select price from customer_price where customer='walmart' and product='whitebread'
```

if this returns a result then all is well. if the result is 0,NULL or the query returns no rows I want this to run:

```
select price from default_price where customer='walmart' and product='whitebread'
```

if this returns a result then all is well. if the result is 0,NULL or the query returns no rows I want to simply return 0.

I am not sure how to proceed. I tried a case statement but the case statement fails if no row is found in the results.  how can I do this or say `if 0 results then`

thanks in advance, as always.

Comment: What does it mean: the case statement fails? Please post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select top 1 price from (
    select 1 as qorder, price from customer_price where price > 0 and customer='walmart' and product='whitebread'
    union
    select 2 as qorder, price from default_price where price > 0 and customer='walmart' and product='whitebread'
    union 
    select 3 as qorder, 0 
    ) as sq
order by qOrder
```

Comment: Does not implement the logic that the default price is returned if the customer price is `null` or zero. Does also not implement the logic that zero is returned if there is no default price. This will just take always the customer price even if it's null or zero.

Comment: Added `price > 0` check

Answer (score 2):

```
case when
(select count(price) from customer_price where customer='walmart' and product='whitebread' and price is not null and price > 0) > 0 
then 
    select price from customer_price where customer='walmart' and product='whitebread'
else 
    select price from default_price where customer='walmart' and product='whitebread'   
end
```

Comment: `count(price)` ? If there are rows with customer='walmart' and product='whitebread' but with price=0 or price=null it will be returned. Does also not handle the case that there is no default price.

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter to bring it to my notice. I have added checks to solve your concerns

Comment: Thanks Pratik, the (select * from...)>0 is exactly what I needed to learn. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a two way solution which includes for both **Empty Select Queries** or **Tables**. *You can replace your query*

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
drop table #temp1

select * into #temp1 from (select col1, col2 from First_Table) as firstTableVariable
if (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    begin
    print 'data is displayed from the first table/query'
        select * from #temp1 
    end
else
    begin
    print 'Data displayed from second table/query '
    select col1, col2 from second_Table 
    end
end
```