# Select from another table if record not found in the first table - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the situation. I have two parameters to query:
Item_code
Item_type

The first_table contains:
Item_Code,Item_Characteristics

The second_table contains:
Item_Type,Item_Characteristics

My goal is to get the item_characteristics. If the specific item is not found in the first table, I would want to use the Item_type to get them from the second table.

Any way this can be done in a single query?

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891453/mssql-select-from-another-table-if-no-results-from-the-first-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this uses `not exists`:

```
select t1.Item_Characteristics
from t1
where t1.item_code = @Item_Code
union all
select t2.Item_Characteristics
from t2
where t2.item_type = @Item_Type and
      not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.item_code = @Item_Code);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a `FULL JOIN` in case `Item_Code` and `Item_Type` are of the same type:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.Item_Characteristics, t2.Item_Characteristics) AS Item_Characteristics
FROM table1 AS t1
FULL JOIN table2 AS t2 
  ON t1.Item_Code = t2.Item_Type
WHERE COALESCE(t1.Item_Code, t2. Item_Type) = @param
```

Comment: I understand the answer (although incorrect), but not the upvote.  The question explicitly specifies two parameters, not one, and makes no suggestion that the tables can be joined like that.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. The parameter to query could be either item_code or item_type based on which one gets me the item_characteristics. If both can get me the item_characteristics, then I would like to go with the item_code which is more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works -

```
select isnull(a.Item_Characteristics,b.item_type)
from first_table as a
left join second_table as b
on a.Item_Characteristics = b.Item_Characteristics
where a.Item_code = @itemcode and b.Item_type = @itemtype
```