# Two SQL query statements, choose only one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two select queries

- if query 1 has a result, then just return that result
- if query 1 doesn't produce a result, then execute query 2

These two queries are from the same table, but query conditions can't co-exist.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please, clarify your question

Comment: Are columns in the select statement same?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense saying that the contitions can't co-exist.  Can the queries return multiple rows?

Comment: @Mopetite `@@ROWCOUNT` system defined variable works best for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860362/1436594

Comment: @Amit Yes,they are same.

Comment: @Amit Yes,they are same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using @@ROWCOUNT...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    SomeNumber INT NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (SomeNumber) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

--=====================================================

SELECT * FROM #TestData td WHERE td.SomeNumber = 22;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM #TestData td WHERE td.SomeNumber <= 5;
END;
```

Comment: I tried to go with this approach but quickly realized that there's a problem because 2 datasets are being returned instead of one, it means the client will have to deal with iterating the 2 datasets instead of one. therefore I would rather go with saving to temp variable/table and returning that

Answer (score 0):

Another method using `IF ELSE`

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name WHERE condition_1 ) = 0) 
    SELECT col_1, col_2, ... col_n FROM table_name WHERE condition_2
ELSE 
    SELECT col_1, col_2, ... col_n FROM table_name WHERE condition_1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check if query1 has result and will set it to a variable. IF ELSE will then check if there's a result for query1 then query1 otherwise query2

```
DECLARE @rec_cnt INT

SET @rec_cnt = (SELECT 1
                  FROM table
                 WHERE condition1)

IF @rec_cnt IS NOT NULL 
   (SELECT *
      FROM table
     WHERE condition1);
ELSE
   (SELECT *
      FROM table
     WHERE condition2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM table1 WHERE condition1)
    SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM table1 WHERE condition1
ELSE 
     SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM table1 WHERE condition2
```